# Program to send messages doesn't recognize some symbols

Tags: python, sublimetext3

It actually works pretty nice, but I need to send a message that contains symbols that are not probably not recognised

The message:⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ɤ ʟᴇɢɪᴏɴᴇᴍ ᴛᴇɴᴇʙʀɪs ɤ  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴅɪᴜ ᴠɪᴠᴇʀᴇ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴇᴛ ᴛᴜ ᴘᴀᴛɪ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸ ɤ ᴘʀɪᴜs ᴍᴏʀɪᴀᴛᴜʀ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ɤ ʟᴇɢɪᴏɴᴇᴍ ᴛᴇɴᴇʙʀɪs ɤ  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴅɪᴜ ᴠɪᴠᴇʀᴇ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴇᴛ ᴛᴜ ᴘᴀᴛɪ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸ ɤ ᴘʀɪᴜs ᴍᴏʀɪᴀᴛᴜʀ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ɤ ʟᴇɢɪᴏɴᴇᴍ ᴛᴇɴᴇʙʀɪs ɤ  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴅɪᴜ ᴠɪᴠᴇʀᴇ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ɤ ᴇᴛ ᴛᴜ ᴘᴀᴛɪ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸ ɤ ᴘʀɪᴜs ᴍᴏʀɪᴀᴛᴜʀ ɤ ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸ ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸  ⸸

```
  File "from selenium import webdriver", line 43, in <module>
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
  File "/Users/familieprivat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Users/familieprivat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/familieprivat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Users/familieprivat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 372, in execute
    data = utils.dump_json(params)
  File "/Users/familieprivat/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/utils.py", line 33, in dump_json
    return json.dumps(json_struct)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

how to make this work?

Comment: Is the message actually UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Check whether this text is actually UTF-8 encoded. My bet is, that it's UTF-16 encoded, which causes some comversion to fail because the character it tries to read just ends halfway through,